# iOS, Set delegate for scene without using segue

Tags: ios, delegates, storyboard, segue, scene

I am trying to navigate to a scene without using a segue. The code I am using looks like this:

```
UIStoryboard * storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:nil];
MyViewController * controller = (MyViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:viewControllerID];
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

My problem is setting the delegate for this scene. Usually I would do the following:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Check the segue identifier
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"])
    {
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDelegate:self];
    }
}
```

But I do not want to use segues. Can anyone please tell me how I could set the delegate for the scene?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UIStoryboard * storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
DetailViewController * controller = (DetailViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailView"];
controller.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

YOu can set the delegate for the scene you are loading.

Your "destinationViewController" will have a method "ViewWillAppear".
There you can set the delegate to self.

Answer (score 0):

as you already have a reference to the new controller you don't need to implement the `prepareForSegue:sender:` method, after the line:

```
MyViewController * controller = (MyViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:viewControllerID];
```

just add:

```
[controller setDelegate:self];
```